Black screen I try to log in to app that I build using firebase Authentication
I developed App that using Firebase Authentication , by mistake I log out and try to log in on non active Account and now I can't run my app , I get black screen ,how I clear the iPhone 15 pro max that iPhone will not try to use the data that gives me the black screen?
I guess that app try to use a key that store on my iPhone and try to login to my firebase project
try to remove all user from firebase Authentication
